# How to make sure the lines don't start with some space?

Tags: indentation

I am formatting a document in LaTeX.

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
Hello\\
This is a Latex Document\\
\begin{flushleft}
How to write without a space in the beginning
\end{flushleft}

Please help



\end{document}
```

I am giving the PDF generated from the below code:

[image]

Two problems:

- Whenever I start the document there is a space with which the document starts
- And when I start with `\begin{flushleft}` and end with `\end{flushleft}`
  the next line again starts with space.

What I want is:
**using some package/some commands so that all my text is aligned to the left. Is it possible? I don't want any space to begin with in a line**.

Comment: Have you tried `\usepackage{parskip}`?

Comment: `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`

Comment: Also note that it is not legal to use \\ outside a tabular environment to start a new line. The only right way way to do so is a blank line.

Comment: @PureMathematics Although I prefer Mico's solution as it looks nicer, I would like to point you to the fact that this package replaces the indentation with a small vertical space between the lines of two paragraphs. This is just for you to understand the difference between those two given solutions.

Comment: @Denis You are mixing up two things: `\\ ` will insert a line break and for that purpose is perfectly suited. Of course, you usually should not insert line breaks manually, but prefer paragraph breaks (blank line or `\par`). But these are two different aims.

Comment: By default standard  document classes of LaTeX have some  paragraph indentation (`\parindent > 0pt`)  except in first paragraphs after headings (`\section`, etc.)  instead of a paragraph skip (`\parskip`  of 0pt). Note also that the end of a paragraph is `\par` or one blank line, whereas  \\  is only a break of line, so with**out** indentation.

Comment: note that the `\\ `  at the ends of paragraph are always wrong (tex will give warnings about badness 10000 (maximum badness)) and give poor output. I

Comment: @Denis No, `\\ ` within a paragraph starts a new line, what is wrong is to force a newline at the end of a paragraph. A blank line in the source doesn't start a new line, it starts a new paragraph.

Comment: Get a couple of books from your shelf: are there indents at the beginning of paragraphs? I guess so. ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Clearly right: I meant using `\\\` to start a new paragraph. Thanks for clarifying.